# Getting list of users that referenced product model

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

```js
 const productSchema = mongoose.Schema(
    {
      user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'User',
      },
      name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      image: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
      },
      price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        default: 0,
      },
    },
    {
      timestamps: true,
    }
  );

const Product = mongoose.model("Product", productSchema);
module.exports = Product;
```

Hello, Please is it possible to get list or count of users that referenced the product model from the product route or model? i know i get get it through the user route but can i do it from the product route?  thanks

Comment: search on how to use `$lookup`, i think you need thiis, or if you can give sample data so a query can be made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Product.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      from: "User", /// name of user collection
      "localField": "user",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "user"
    }
  },
])
```

this will add user object as user in product doc as array, so you could have all data of user here and list of them

Comment: this returns user as an empty array:   router.get(
  "/counts",
  catchAsync(async (req, res) => {
    const stats = await User.aggregate([
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: "Product",
          localField: "_id",
          foreignField: "user",
          as: "count",
        },
      },
    ]);
    if (!stats) {
      return res.status(404).json("No data found");
    }
    res.status(200).json(stats);
  })
);

Comment: Check the collection name in lookup